# Is it possible to extend a custom Validator in TYPO3 to prevent double typing functions?

Tags: validation, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I have two Validators in my Extension.

In both extensions i have same functions e.g. `isTagInside()`.

I don't want to have this functions two times, if i change the 1. isTagInside(), i have to change the 2. isTagInside() too. It feels like bad practice here and repeating code. ;)

---

My Controllers use a BaseController, where functions are stored, that i use in both Controllers. So i can split also CRUD processes and other functions. I use it like this, and it works perfect.

```
class UserController extends \RM\RmRegistration\Controller\BaseController
```

---

The same i want in my Validators, but this:

```
27: class NewRegisteredUserValidator extends \RM\RmRegistration\Validation\Validator\BaseValidator
```

27: is just the line-number ;)

results in this ErrorMessage

> Fatal error: Class 'RM\RmRegistration\Validation\Validator\BaseValidator' not found in /var/www/devserver/rmupdate/typo3conf/ext/rm_registration/Classes/Validation/Validator/NewRegisteredUserValidator.php on line 27

---

Does somebody know a working solution for this issue OR is this just not possible?

Comment: are you sure you have added **BaseValidator.php** file in correct path?

Comment: Yes the BaseValidator is in the directory: `rm_registration/Classes/Validation/Validator` and it extends the AbstractValidator with this line `class BaseValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator`

Comment: After added this changes once you nedd to install / un-install extension. did you do this?

Comment: No, i'll try this.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot, write your answer, so i can Voteup, and accept your answer ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check `BaseValidator.php` file Path. it's correct or Not.

If `BaseValidator.php` file Path is correct and after added this all changes you need to once `Install / Un-install` extension and clear `Install Tool` cache.

After check once again and now i think it's works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the BaseValidator i had to add the empty function isValid() with a $value, otherwise the extending doesn't works.

```
/**
 * Initial function to validate
 * It has to be here (empty and with a $value-variable),
 * otherwise the BaseValidator does not works !!!
 */
protected function isValid($value)
{
}
```